# mingw32-make: No Targets. Stop

Tags: mingw32

I am following this simple [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttYspMwzV8w&t=214s). But when I use mingw32-make it outputs `mingw32-make: *** No targets.  Stop.` I am in the same folder as the Makefile when I executed it. I have no idea how to fix it and I coud not find anything about it. If you know the fix please help me.

Comment: What does your makefile look like ?

Comment: @Pierre `all: compile link

compile:
 g++ -I src/include -c main.cpp
link:
 g++ main.o -o main -L src/lib -l sfml-graphics -l smfl-window -l sfml-system`
It is really simple.

Comment: Did you try with `mingw32-make -f <your_makefile_name>`  ?

Comment: @Pierre Yes same result. My makefile is just called Makefile. I also tried changing its name to makefile. Its the same.

Comment: I found the problem: I made the Makefile in VS Code and I didn't save it so the whole time it was empty. Thanks for trying to help me tho. (Sorry for my bad english)